# Gradual transition of my development environment from a MAMP stack to Docker?

Tags: docker, mamp

Context: I am planning to switch to Docker for my localhost development environment.
I have my localhost development-enviroment setup on a Mac with MAMP (lot of different vhosts), composer, git etcetera.

Question:
Is it possible to have a docker based environment and my old environment next to each other, so I could start trying out one project in docker but in the mean time run my current project in the old stack?
Because I have like 20+ projects running and no time to rebuild everyting, or even worse, mess up my production sites and projects....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can run the Docker based environment alongside your old environment. The container technology allows to isolate all required dependencies for each project in a container image.

You only have to be careful with the port mapping, i.e. the ports which are already used by MAMP must not be used for mapping.